# How to use a SubQueryExpression in QueryDSL BooleanExpression

Tags: java, hibernate, subquery, querydsl

I have tow entities linked by a @ManyToMany, Criterias and Rules. Both can be activated or not, and Rules can also be critical or not. They have corresponding field in their entities. I need a query retrieving only the Criterias who are actived AND which have at least one activated critical rule.

Here is how I though writing a subquery would work:

```
BooleanExpression subExpression = QRule.rule.enable.eq(true).and(QRule.rule.critical.eq(true));

BooleanExpression expr = QCriteria.criteria.enable.eq(true)
            .and(QCriteria.criteria.rules.any().eq(subExpression));
List<Criteria> crits = criteriaRepository.findAll(expr);
```

I've seen that the .eq() where I use the subexpression can take a SubQueryExpression but I cannot find any information on how to use them.

I am using QueryDSL 4.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an exists subquery to model the "have at least one actived critical rule" requirement.